# How to specify cluster location in HADOOP_CONF_DIR?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

The Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) about submitting applications says:

> Connect to a YARN cluster in client or cluster mode depending on the value of --deploy-mode. The cluster location will be found based on the HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR variable.

I am afraid I did not get it. I found that `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is set to `/etc/hadoop` that contains many shell scripts and configuration files.

Where exactly should I find the cluster location there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is the directory with the configuration files that Hadoop libraries use for various Hadoop-specific stuff. I wrote *various Hadoop-specific stuff* to highlight that there's not much here Spark-related.

What's more important is that `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` can also point to an empty directory (which says to assume the defaults).

To answer your question, you can define the cluster location in [yarn-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) using `yarn.resourcemanager.address`. If `yarn-site.xml` is not found, the YARN cluster is available at localhost.

> Where should I place `yarn-site.xml` so `spark-submit` will use it?

I used to use `YARN_CONF_DIR` to point to the directory with `yarn-site.xml`.

```
YARN_CONF_DIR=/tmp ./bin/spark-shell --master yarn
```